# how to convert date to other format with special chars

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'd like to convert date to such format:

> 2017%2C01%2C02

was trying to do this using:

```
date.strftime('%Y%2Cm%2Cd')
```

But is doesn't work.

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong and how to solve it ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for `strftime` to print % as a literal string, you need to escape it by doing `%%`. You also need to add another `%` in front of `m` and `d`  like you did with Year, if you want them to be replaced by actual month and dates.

This [cheat sheet](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) is quite helpful.